# Localization is not working properly in Xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, localization, xcode7

I am using localization in my application. Before Xcode 7, all visuals were traslated without a problem. I ve faced a weird problem with Xcode 7. Some parts of the application is not being translated. For example one of UINavigationItem is not translated. Here is how I translate it like others:

```
"tdw-ch-DPh.title" = "İletişim";
```

I have uninstalled the app and installed again and tried to change the translated text to English chars. Not working. As I mentioned, there are only few items not translated. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you use NSLocalizedString ? Or a language specific storyboard ?

Comment: I am translating a storyboard item not with NSLocalizedString.

Comment: Prefer NSLocalizedString.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use NSLocalization.
Create a string file and say:

```
Test 1 = "Test String 1";
Test 2 = "Test String 2";
```

In your code say (for example):

```
NSString *TheFirstTest = NSLocalizedString(@"Test String 1", @"");
NSString *TheSecondTest = NSLocalizedString(@"Test String 2", @"");
NSLog(@" 1. %@ \r 2. %@ ", TheFirstTest, TheSecondTest);
```

And if you want to localize your storyboard, just click localize (Identity Inspector -> Identity and Type -> Localization) and Xcode'll create multiple storyboards in different languages.